# Как сделать скошенные углы с помощью css?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Собственно, вся суть вопроса заключена в заголовке поста. Изображение должно иметь скошенные края и выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если только сделать некий div, в котором находятся 4 элемента по углам в виде треугольников, которые этот див перекрывают. На данный момент скорее всего только так

Comment: Предполагается, что изображение "обёрнуто" в `div`. Я думал, с помощью псевдоклассов `:before` и `:after` для этого дива такую вещь как-то можно реализовать..

Comment: дело в том, что :before  и :after - это два элемента. а нужно 4. Да и то вообще всё зависит будет ли фон сзади таких картинок, чтоб можно было у этих треугольников фон задать или именно это должно быть обрезкой/прозрачным, тогда даже всевдоэлементы, наверное, не помогут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вариант с поворотами

Можно завернуть фото в обёртку и повернуть фото на 45 градусов в одну сторону, а обёртку — на 45 градусов в другую.

Чтобы уменьшить отрезанные уголки, фото уменьшаем, а обёртку увеличиваем в одинаковое количество раз.

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/YpWepz

```css
.cut-corners {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px; width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cut-corners > div {
  height: 125%; width: 125%; /* = 5/4 */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5%; left: -12.5%;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.cut-corners > div > img {
  display: block;
  height: 80%; width: 80%; /* = 4/5 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%; left: 10%;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.cut-corners.demo {
  background: orange;
  margin: 180px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.cut-corners.demo > div {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cut-corners"><div><img src="//placehold.it/400x400/936/fff/?text=cut%20corners" alt=""></div></div>

<div class="cut-corners demo"><div><img src="//placehold.it/400x400/936/fff/?text=%20%20%20demo%20%20%20%20" alt=""></div></div>
```

Comment: Вот этот вариант нормальный!

Comment: Кстати, @АлексейШиманский, псевдоэлементами таки можно решить вопрос, суть аналогична предложению в данном ответе: повернутый на 45 градусов псевдоэлемент с белым бордером и прозрачным фоном)

Comment: @Игорь но белый бордер это угол будет, так? А тогда это неэффективно применять на различного рода бэкграундах. Только на белом. А тут вроде как везде можно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, я больше к тому, что решение вопроса псевдоэлементами все же существует, пусть и как выяснилось, не самое оптимальное

Answer (score 3):

Если вдруг не особо важны [не самые свежайшие браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path):

```css
div {
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGmki.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 320px;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
      25px 0%, calc(100% - 25px) 0%, 
      100% 25px, 100% calc(100% - 25px), 
      calc(100% - 25px) 100%, 25px 100%, 
      0% calc(100% - 25px), 0% 25px);
  clip-path: polygon(
      25px 0%, calc(100% - 25px) 0%, 
      100% 25px, 100% calc(100% - 25px), 
      calc(100% - 25px) 100%, 25px 100%, 
      0% calc(100% - 25px), 0% 25px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: бедные IE и EDGE пользователи)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да и Firefox тоже. Ну, может, через пару лет ответ станет актуальным, мало ли кто тогда будет гуглить, ему поможет. Или, возможно, если речь идёт о чём-то вроде приложения на NW.js. :)

Answer (score 2):

Самое лучшее и кроссбраузерное и адаптивно это вырезать в графическом редакторе нужную форму с прозрачностью , вот пример того что сделано таким образом:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 3px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/border.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.heard:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/heard.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <img src="https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1366x768/f/64/anita-sikorska-devushka-3093.jpg" lt="">
</div>

<div class="">
  <img src="https://im3-tub-kz.yandex.net/i?id=43a29f50e02f2c4e25348e496aea3e5c&n=33&h=213&w=160" lt="">
</div>

<div class="heard">
  <img src="http://picview.info/download/20150816/eyes-model-portrait-woman-blue-hair-2560x1600.jpg" lt="">
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Жаль только не очень хорошо сработает, если размеры и пропорции изображения варьируются, как тут, а скос нужен фиксированный. Как вариант, можно использовать сразу несколько изображений в `background` через запятую, по одному для каждого угла, работать будет [везде с IE>8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

Ещё, конечно, не очень-то решает задачу, если под изображением фон не будет белым.

Comment: зато 100% кроссбраузерно , svg или  -webkit-clip-path не решение, поверьте

Comment: про `clip-path`, конечно, не поспоришь, но что не так с SVG? IE8?

Comment: геморой его создавать , хотя если привыкнуть...

Comment: Вглядывался я, вглядывался и не обнаружил скошенных углов ͡๏̯͡๏

Comment: @АлексейШиманский щас видно углы ?

Comment: @Geyan да. надеюсь не только мне)